# I can't access my inherited values in c#

Tags: c#, interface

I have an interface that looks like this:

```
public interface ISelectSpace
{
    bool ShowSpaceSelection { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<Space> AvailableSpaces { get; set; }
}
```

I then have another interface that looks like this:

```
public interface ISelectSingleSpace : ISelectSpace
{
    string Space { get; set; }
    string SpaceName { get; set; }
}
```

However, when I try and access my list of IEnumerables of the variable AvailableSpaces, I can't use the count function like this:

```
public static class SelectSingleSpace
{
    public static void DoStuff(this ISelectSingleSpace selectSingleSpace)
    {
        Console.Write(selectSingleSpace.AvailableSpaces.Count());
    }
}
```

Am I not referencing the variable correctly?

I initialize this method like this in another class:

```
var selectSingleSpace = this as ISelectSingleSpace;
selectSingleSpace.DoStuff();
```

Comment: Are you `using System.Linq;`?  I have a feeling it's the `Count()` extension method that's causing the problem, not your interface properties.

Comment: By "can't use", what do you mean. Are you getting an error?

Comment: I don't remember it you need to use Count().ToString()

Comment: I'm not getting an error. It's just not actually counting the amount of things in the list and instead prints 0. Thanks

Comment: I just copy/pasted the code into my VS2012, and it compiled fine.  What exact error are you seeing?

Comment: Can you show how you're initializing your ISelectSingleSpace object and calling DoStuff?

Comment: Ok... that addition doesn't help much.  What's in `this`?

Comment: Let's try another tack - are you certain that there are > 0 items in the collection?  Set a breakpoint in the extension method, and check out the contents of the enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
(I had trouble acessing some extension methods using the `this` keyword in derived classes, maybe it's something like that. In the code below, I try to trick this around)

```
public static class SelectSingleSpace
{
    public static void DoStuff(this ISelectSingleSpace selectSingleSpace)
    {
        IEnumerable<Space> AvailableSpaces = selectSingleSpace.AvailableSpaces;
        Console.Write(AvailableSpaces.Count());
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this. Thanks for the help but I'm afraid it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The parts of the code that you have shown are all fine. The issues that you are having is in something that you are not showing. I have pasted the following code into a VS project and this has compiled and worked:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace SO16390592
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            ISelectSingleSpace test = new Test();
            test.AvailableSpaces = new List<Space>(new Space[1]);
            test.DoStuff();
        }
    }

    public class Space
    {

    }

    public interface ISelectSpace
    {
        bool ShowSpaceSelection { get; set; }
        IEnumerable<Space> AvailableSpaces { get; set; }
    }


    public interface ISelectSingleSpace : ISelectSpace
    {
        string Space { get; set; }
        string SpaceName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Test : ISelectSingleSpace
    {
        public bool ShowSpaceSelection { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Space> AvailableSpaces { get; set; }
        public string Space { get; set; }
        public string SpaceName { get; set; }
    }


    public static class SelectSingleSpace
    {
        public static void DoStuff(this ISelectSingleSpace selectSingleSpace)
        {
            Console.Write(selectSingleSpace.AvailableSpaces.Count());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what was printed at the console:

> > 1

Here is online demo: http://ideone.com/O2EAak

I suggest you either show us more code illustrating you problem, or better yet, create a standalone reproducible case for us that exhibits your issue.